# Callback event when jQuery 'mmenu' opened

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mmenu

Using the jQuery [mmenu plugin](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) I need to call a JavaScript function after the menu has finished opening.  I can't see from the [API documentation](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/api.html) how to do this using the plug-in API, so I'm thinking perhaps the only option is to observe the class name on the `<html>` element, which gains a class of `mm-opened` when the menu is opened.  This feels a little 'hacky' though, so I wondered if anyone could see a way, within the bounds of the native API, to accomplish the required function call?

EDIT: Contrary to expectations the `openPanel` event doesn't fire when the menu is opened - it only fires when sub-menus are opened, so although this suggests it would do the job, it doesn't.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got it (not documented!):

```
var api = $('#menu').data('mmenu');
api.bind('opened', function () {
    console.log('opened');
});
```

Comment: got caught out by the same thing, this helped me out. There's also a 'closed' event if anyone needs to bind to it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the latest version of the plugin, can you confirm?

Comment: I confirm, hate this, spent the last 3 hours trying to hook myself in the events of this thing.

Comment: Works for me in latest release.

Comment: In 6.1.7 I had success with `.bind('open:finish', function() { });`

Comment: @ChezFre is right. Current version requires 'open:finish' as the event name.

Comment: With 8.5.18 it's now `.bind('open:after', function() { });` and
    `.bind('close:after', function() { });`

Answer (score 6):

You may search for `.trigger(` on the source code:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu/master/dist/js/jquery.mmenu.min.js

You will find the following events:

- init
- update
- setSelected
- setPage
- open
- opening
- opened
- close
- closing
- closed
- openPanel
- openingPanel
- openedPanel
- closePanel
- closingPanel
- closedPanel

I believe those are it. Among them you can see the 'opened' and 'closed' events that will be useful for your case.

Answer (score 3):

```
var api = self.$el.data("mmenu");

api.bind('close:finish', function() {
   console.log('close');
});

api.bind('open:finish', function () {
   console.log('open');
});
```

Thanks to ChezFre