# Mmenu - How do I detect the closed call back event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, mmenu

I am using the [Jquery Mmenu plugin](https://mmenujs.com/) and I want to detect when the closed call back event occurs so I can remove a css class from my burger menu. I have the same burger menu icon that opens and closes the menu, I am adding an `is-active` class when the menu opens but I need to detect when the whole menu has closed so I can remove the class and I can't seem to figure it out.

This is what I have so far:

```
document.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const menu = new Mmenu( "#mobile-menu", {
            "extensions": [
                "position-front"
            ],
            scrollBugFix: {
                fix: true
            },
    });
    const api = menu.API;
    const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');

    hamburger.addEventListener(
       "click", ( evnt ) => {
           evnt.preventDefault();
           hamburger.classList.add("is-active");
     });
    }
);


  [1]: https://mmenujs.com/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in the comments on this question: [Callback event when jQuery 'mmenu' opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559505/callback-event-when-jquery-mmenu-opened?rq=1)

Adding:

```
// When the open callback event is fired bind to it and add the class
api.bind('open:after', function (){
    hamburger.classList.add('is-active');
    console.log('open')
})

// When the closed callback event is fired bind to it and remove the class
api.bind('close:after', function(){
    hamburger.classList.remove("is-active");
    console.log('closed')
})

The documentation for the plugin is good but not that great so I struggled for a while before seeing this. Maybe it can help someone else.

I am using the latest version of the plugin and that is 8 something.
```

Comment: Thanks @Neelam, this is super useful and worked in my case! Please do share more knowledge regarding mmenu.js.